# Email attachment is delivered without an extension

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have some code to email some results as an attachment.  The attachment is showing up without an extension and I cannot open it.  Any suggestions on how I can get the attachment to show up as working extension?

```
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;
.....
String path=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//"+reportFileName;
Zip.zip(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//"+ReportUtil.result_FolderName,reportFileName);
.....
DataSource source = 
new FileDataSource(attachmentPath);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(
new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName(attachmentName);
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

Comment: Holy mother of god! BATMAN!

Comment: Well, what is the value of `attachmentName`?

Comment: `String attachmentPath`, which links with `path` which links to `String path=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//"+reportFileName;`

Comment: And does it end in an extension?

Comment: I appreciate your help, just a bit confused.  Do you suggest adding a .zip after reportFileName?

Comment: @user2195411: well, `attachmentName` is the name given to the attachment. If it *does not end in `.zip`* then the file name the user sees will not end in `.zip`. I thought that much would be obvious.